# What is the custom URL scheme of check-in for Facebook event by the Facebook iPhone/Android app?

Tags: facebook, events, url, checkin

Does anyone know about the custom URL scheme of check-in for a Facebook event within the Facebook iPhone/Android app?

The custom URL schemes of check-in for Facebook places are:

- fb://place/[place id] on iPhone
- fb://place/fw?pid=[place id] on Android

Comment: Would also like to know...